# Forward filling missing dates into Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Panda's dataframe that is filled as follows:

```
ref_date    tag
1/29/2010   1
2/26/2010   3
3/31/2010   4
4/30/2010   4
5/31/2010   1
6/30/2010   3
8/31/2010   1
9/30/2010   4
12/31/2010  2
```

Note how there are missing months (i.e. 7, 10, 11) in the data. I want to fill in the missing data through a forward filling method so that it looks like this:

```
ref_date    tag
1/29/2010   1
2/26/2010   3
3/31/2010   4
4/30/2010   4
5/31/2010   1
6/30/2010   3
7/30/2010   3
8/31/2010   1
9/30/2010   4
10/29/2010  4
11/30/2010  4
12/31/2010  2
```

The tag of the missing date will have the **tag of the previous**. All dates represent the **last business day** of the month.

This is what I tried to do:

```
idx = pd.date_range(start='1/29/2010', end='12/31/2010', freq='BM')
df.ref_date.index = pd.to_datetime(df.ref_date.index)
df = df.reindex(index=[idx], columns=[ref_date], method='ffill')
```

It's giving me the error:

> TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'int'

where `pd` is pandas and `df` is the dataframe.

I'm new to Pandas Dataframe, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: this line doesn't look correct to me `df.ref_date.index = pd.to_datetime(df.ref_date.index)` should be more like `df.set_index = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close, you just need to set the dataframe's index with the `ref_date`, reindex it to the business day month end index while specifying `ffill` at the method, then reset the index and rename back to the original:

```
# First ensure the dates are Pandas Timestamps.
df['ref_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ref_date'])

# Create a monthly index.
idx_monthly = pd.date_range(start='1/29/2010', end='12/31/2010', freq='BM')

# Reindex to the daily index, forward fill, reindex to the monthly index.
>>> (df
     .set_index('ref_date')
     .reindex(idx_monthly, method='ffill')
     .reset_index()
     .rename(columns={'index': 'ref_date'}))
     ref_date  tag
0  2010-01-29  1.0
1  2010-02-26  3.0
2  2010-03-31  4.0
3  2010-04-30  4.0
4  2010-05-31  1.0
5  2010-06-30  3.0
6  2010-07-30  3.0
7  2010-08-31  1.0
8  2010-09-30  4.0
9  2010-10-29  4.0
10 2010-11-30  4.0
11 2010-12-31  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the previous person that answered this question but deleted his answer. I got the solution:

```
df[ref_date] = pd.to_datetime(df[ref_date])
idx = pd.date_range(start='1/29/2010', end='12/31/2010', freq='BM')
df = df.set_index(ref_date).reindex(idx).ffill().reset_index().rename(columns={'index': ref_date})
```

Comment: My original solution didn't match your expected output, so I deleted it.  New version has been reposted.

Comment: Sorry about that, I made a bunch of typos. Thanks a lot for helping!